# why am i getting Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference?

Tags: android

```
enter code here`
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AlbumAdapter adapter;
public List<Album> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    new MovieAsyncTask().execute("");






    adapter = new AlbumAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class MovieAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Album> >
{


    public List<Album>  getMovieDataFromJson(String str)
    {
        List<Album> albumArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String ImageUrilink = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/";
        final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
        final String RATING = "vote_average";
        final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String releaseDate = jsonObject1.getString(RELEASE_DATE);
                String rating = jsonObject1.getDouble(RATING)+"/10";
                String image = ImageUrilink+jsonObject1.getString(POSTER_PATH);
                albumArrayList.add(new Album(rating,releaseDate,image));
            }
            String size = jsonArray.length()+" ITEM";
            Log.v("SIZE OF ALBUMLIST = ",size);

            return albumArrayList;
        }
        catch (JSONException j)
        {
            j.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Album>  doInBackground(String... params) {


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        String readJson  ;

        final String Sortby = "sort_by";
        final String APPID_PARAM = "api_key";


        try {


            String movieUri = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
            Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(movieUri).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(Sortby,"popularity.desc")
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM,BuildConfig.MOVIE_API_KEY).build();

            URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());

            Log.v("LOG_TAG",buildUri.toString());

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            if(inputStream==null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            if(stringBuffer==null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            readJson = stringBuffer.toString();
            return getMovieDataFromJson(readJson);

        }catch (IOException I)
        {
            I.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(httpURLConnection!=null)
            {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if(reader!=null)
            {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                }catch(IOException I)
                {
                    I.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Album> albumList) {

        if(!albumList.isEmpty())
        {
            super.onPostExecute(albumList);
            list = albumList;
        }

    }
}
```

}

public class AlbumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context mcontext;
private List<Album> albumList;



public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView rating, releaseDate;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        rating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        releaseDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnails);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
    }
}

public AlbumAdapter(Context mcontext1, List<Album> albumList1) {
    mcontext = mcontext1;
    albumList = albumList1;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Album album = albumList.get(position);
    holder.rating.setText(album.getRating());
    holder.releaseDate.setText(album.getReleaseDate()+" Songs ");

    Picasso.with(mcontext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    Log.v("IMAGE_URL",album.getThumbnail());

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopUp(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * showing popup menu wher tapping on 3 dots
 */
private void showPopUp(View view)
{
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mcontext,view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album,popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite :
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Add to favourite",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_play_next :
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Play next",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return albumList.size();
}
```

}

**Exception**

```
11-13 15:07:00.587 26661-26661/com.example.sanket3125.cardgridviewexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sanket3125.cardgridviewexample, PID: 26661
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.sanket3125.cardgridviewexample.AlbumAdapter.getItemCount(AlbumAdapter.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3225)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2837)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2645)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2127)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1243)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your List variable in onCreate() before using it in the adapter.

```
new MovieAsyncTask().execute("");
list = new ArrayList<Album>();
adapter = new AlbumAdapter(this, list);
```

Also, once you have your results in the onPostExecute() method, you need to tell the adapter to reload your list :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Album> albumList) {

    if(albumList != null && !albumList.isEmpty())
    {
        super.onPostExecute(albumList);
        list = albumList;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```